# Numeral: Date. Confused when last digit is three

Tags: перевод, грамматика, словоупотребление

How do I spell (and pronounce) the twenty third of October in Russian?

Comment: Числительное **23**, podcast `00:00:33--00:00:36` [link](http://media.govoritmoskva.ru/broadcasts/audio/2015/09/23/2015_09_23_Podem.mp3) ||| Слово **октября**, podcast   `00:00:34--00:00:36` [link](http://media.govoritmoskva.ru/broadcasts/audio/2015/10/02/2015_10_02_Podem.mp3)

Answer (score 2):

"October 23" would be *двадцать третье октября* ([dvɐt͡sɨ#'trʲetʲjɪ əktʲɪbrʲä])

You use neuter gender for the ordinal here because it agrees with assumed noun *число* ("number") which is neuter.

Answer (score 1):

The 6 cases for it in their usual order (only "третье" changes):

`Двадцать третье октября` (what day it is)

`(От) двадцать третьего октября` (when, letter /of/ what date, on what date)

`(К) двадцать третьему октября` (/by what date/, to what day devoted)

`Двадцать третье октября` (the day one might remember)

`Двадцать третьим октября` (smth. ends with that day or marked with that date written)

`На двадцать третьем октября` (we've finally come to agreement on that day for our next meeting)

Comment: How do you pronunce "третье" --> "tre-chi" andfor третьего --> "trech-evo"?

Comment: "третье" => "TREH-t'yeh", "третьего" => "TREH-t'ee-vah" (normally) or "TREH-t'yeh-goh" (when pronounced distinctly and slowly)

Comment: you can listen to examples here at Google Translate: https://translate.google.ru/?hl=ru&tab=wT#ru/en/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%0A%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE – just click on the speakerphone icon

Comment: Pronounce "третье" as "треть-е".  The same with "третьего" = "треть-ева", the emphasis is on the *треть*.  A the end of each there is a shwa (the 'е' or 'о' without emphasis).